# Reformulation of Convex Constraints

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, constraints, second-order-cone-programming

I am trying to reformulate the constraints

$$
\alpha^\intercal L \beta + \|L^\intercal \alpha\|_{2}^{2} \leq \rho,
$$

where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^{n},\beta\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$ and $\rho\in\mathbb{R}$ are constants, and $L\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ is the decision variable of interest. These constraints are quadratic constraints, and I believe they are convex because I know that $L$ has full row rank.

However, I am having trouble formulating these constraints in a more standard/canonical form, such as second-order cone constraints (SOCC). My main issue is with the linear term $\alpha^\intercal L\beta$ that does not split up nicely as $\|z\|_2^2$, for example. Any help or insights on these constraints would be incredibly helpful!

Comment: $\rho - \alpha^TL\beta \geq \|L^T\alpha\|_2^2$

Comment: But isn't a cone constraint defined in terms of the norm of a vector, not the norm *squared*?

Comment: They are equivalent by a linear transformation, the one with squared norm is usually called the rotated quadratic cone, for details see https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#conic-quadratic-optimization